# Automatic generation of SQL comments

Tags: mysql, sql, comments

I'm using a application with MySQL support. But before using I must import many big .sql files of this application to DB. And this is what I see in one .sql file:

```
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
...
(x, id_from_table_1, xx, xxx), -- name_from_table_1_for_given_id
...
```

so I can very easily understand meaning of every row's id. How someone generated this comments?

Comment: `IMPORT INTO`?  That doesn't look like MySQL.  `INSERT INTO`, perhaps?  Are there no comments at the beginning of the file that indicate how it was generated? Many tools identify themselves this way. If not, then it is likely custom code written for a specific purpose of creating backup files that would be especially human-readable.  Why do you ask?

Comment: Sure, `INSERT INTO`, typo, sorry. There is comments at the beginning of the file, but they only about file structure. I am asking because I changed this file and for future work it will be useful to me to have this comments. At this time, easiest for me method to make such comments is: write MySQL JOIN query to get the names for the ID's and then unite them in .sql file using Notepad++. But may be there is easy way?